# Filter nested query if no results in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have three basic nested serializers that are currently returning a nested data structure (shown below) when I use this query:

```py
queryset = Regulation.objects.all() 
serializer_class = RegulationSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

My **models.py** is as follow:

```
class Regulation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.TextField(null=False)
    documents = models.ManyToManyField(Document, related_name='regulation_documents', through="DocumentRegulation")
    portal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class RegulationVersion(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regulation = models.ForeignKey(Regulation, related_name='versions', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)

class Iteration(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    version = models.ForeignKey(RegulationVersion, related_name='iterations', blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
    created_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        unique_together= ('name', 'organization', 'version')
```

With the **serializers.py** structured as:

```
class FilteredIterationSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        organization_id = self.context.get('organization_id')
        data = data.filter(organization=organization_id)
        return super(FilteredIterationSerializer, self).to_representation(data)python

class IterationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Iteration
        list_serializer_class = FilteredIterationSerializer
        fields = ('id', 'organization', 'version', 'name', 'date_created', 'created_by_user')

class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    iterations = IterationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RegulationVersion
        fields = ('name', 'iterations')

class RegulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    versions = VersionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Regulation
        fields = ('name', 'versions')
        depth = 2
```

**serialized output:**

```
[{ name: "2019-final"
  versions: {
       0: { name: "2019-01",
            iterations: (25) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
          }
       1: { name: "2019-02",
            iterations: []
          }
 }
{ name: "2020-final"
  versions: {
       0: { name: "2020-01",
            iterations: []
          }
       1: { name: "2020-02",
            iterations: []
          }
 }]
```

How do I ***exclude*** all of the `versions` without any `iterations`, and also *exclude* the `regulations` without any `versions` or nested `iterations`.

Using the above serialized output, I would not want to return the object where `name` is `"2020-final"`, because none of its `versions` have `iterations`. I would also not want to return the `version` object where `name` is `"2019-02"`, because it has no iterations. The desired output would look like this:

```
[{ name: "2019-final"
  versions: {
       0: { name: "2019-01",
            iterations: (25) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
          }
 }]
```

Comment: Can you also add your `models.py` code for all of the models involved?

Comment: Please include the code for `FilteredIterationSerializer` too, as well as any `django-filters` code you might be using.

Comment: Thanks so much for cleaning up the question... I have never seen such a beautifully formatted question. I hesitate to put too much code sometimes, not wanting to overwhelm someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:**

Whenever any nested serializer has `many=True` argument passed, DRF creates a list serializer instance behind the scene (check `BaseSerializer.__new__` and `BaseSerializer.many_init` methods), with keeping the original serializer as the `child` class-attribute of the list serializer. Then whenever serialization is needed (when you access `serializer.data`), as usual, the `to_representation` of the list serializer is called, the list serializer then, in turn, calls `to_representation` of the `child` serializer and returns a list as output.

The default list serializer is `serializers.ListSerializer`, it be changed via the serializer `Meta` class option `list_serializer_class`.

So if we need to change the representation, we need to create our list serializer class and override `to_representation` to return the modified response.

---

At first, let's handle the `VersionSerializer` to only show the versions that have related iteration(s):

```
class VersionListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        versions = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data 
        return [
            self.child.to_representation(version)
            for version in versions
            if version.iterations.exists()
        ]

class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
  iterations = IterationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
      model = RegulationVersion
      list_serializer_class = VersionListSerializer
      fields = ('name', 'iterations')
```

Similar logic for `RegulationSerializer`, showing only the regulations that have related version(s):

```
class RegulationListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        regulations = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data 
        return [
            self.child.to_representation(regulation)
            for regulation in regulations
            if regulation.versions.exists()
        ]

class RegulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    versions = VersionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Regulation
        list_serializer_class = RegulationListSerializer
        fields = ('name', 'versions')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is amazing. In the condition that there are no iterations, and the versions are removed, it still returns the regulation, but I believe that is because the RegulationListSerializer is evaluated before the VersionListSerializer. If there are actually no versions for a regulation, this works as expected. In my case, that is actually alright, because I can just count the number of versions listed, and if it zero, remove it from the array. This is a lot simpler than recursively counting the versions AND the iterations, and then removing the regulation if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @ambe5960 The filtering on Regulation should work. Change `serializer_class` to just `RegulationSerializer` and then see. Also did you change anything regarding serializer in your viewset's `list` method?